# How do you change what jsx blocks are being rendered from inside a same class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm still learning the basics of React, and I wanted to do something that caught my attention. It's about rendering two things. Is it possible or even plausible to just change what is rendered with a function, and then calling the functions separately with a button or timer?

This is a sample code, to show how it would render two completely different things. It is supposed to render a button that says "State: On" or "State: Off". And when you click the button the state changes. But also, the whole render method is switched... or at least that's what's supposed to be happening.

```
class Flicker{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {mode: "on"};
    }
    flipOn(){
        this.setState({mode: "on"})
    }
    flipOff(){
        this.setState({mode: "off"})
    }
    if (this.state.mode == "on"){
        render() {
            return(
                <button onClick={this.flipOn}>State: On</button>
            );
        }
    } else if (this.state.mode == "off"){
        render() {
            return(
                <button onClick={this.flipOff}>State: Off</button>
            );
        }
    }
}
export default Flicker;
```

If this isn't the correct way to do this type of changes in what jsx gets rendered on the app, how should it be done?

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea - but in a class there is only one render method.  Your logic does belong inside the render.  This should do what you're looking for:

```js
class Flicker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {mode: "On"};
    }

    flipOn(){
        this.setState({mode: "On"})
    }

    flipOff(){
        this.setState({mode: "Off"})
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <button onClick={(this.state.mode === 'Off') ? this.flipOn : this.flipOff}>State: {this.state.mode}</button>
        )
    }
}

export default Flicker;
```

Comment: flipOff never called in your code also without extending the React Component how does this class would work

Comment: Thanks - edited accordingly.  @Dan, it's very flexible - basically your logic does belong in the render, but how you choose to do that is up to you.  I believe that returning a different button based on the state is a little overkill.  You can use the same button with different properties, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Put the conditional logic inside the render() method.

Something like this...

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  // the rest of your code

  render() {
     const { mode } = this.state;
          return(
              <div>
                 {mode ==="on" && <button onClick={this.flipOn}>State: On</button> }
                 {mode === "off" && <button onClick={this.flipOff}>State: Off</button>}
               </div>
          )
    }
}
```

Comment: So it would be: render>logic>return?

Comment: Thank you Filip, this is exactly what i needed to know!

Comment: @Flip I edited your answer. It won’t be good to use if else in render. Take a look at edited answer and let me know if you have any queries

Answer (score 2):

Your component changes the state. The state is boolean - either on (true) or not (false). Since you're state is switched between two value, you can use a single method (`toggle`). Since we check the previous state, it it's better to [setState via updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

You need to bind the [method to `this`](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56), by using bind in the constructor (method 4) or an arrow function via an instance method (method 5).

Now in the (single) render, you only need to change the `text` according to the state of `on`:

```js
class Flicker extends React.Component{
  state = { on: true };

  toggle = () =>
    this.setState(({ on }) => ({ on: !on }));

  render() {
    const text = this.state.on ? 'On' : 'Off';

    return (
      <button onClick={this.toggle}>State: {text}</button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Flicker />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

**Real world example**

The button should probably get `on` and `toggle` via props. Now they are available outside, and the Flicker's only concern is calling `toggle` when it's clicked, and changing the text according to `on`:

```js
const Toggler = ({ on, toggle }) => (
  <button onClick={toggle}>
    State: {on ? 'On' : 'Off'}
  </button>
);

class Flicker extends React.Component {
  state = { on: true };

  toggle = () =>
    this.setState(({ on }) => ({ on: !on }));
  
  render() {
    const { on } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div>
        <Toggler toggle={this.toggle} on={on} />
        {on &&
          'I\'m displayed only when I\'m On'
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Flicker />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: What if the state rendered also renders text or a form or something else, and the state changing button? Does this also work for things such as that?

Comment: This is a button, a button should be simple. If you want something more complicated, create other simple components and compose them together. In this case, the button shouldn't have a state of it's own. In should get the `on` state via prop, and a callback to change the state of `on` in a parent. Now you can do whatever you want with the `on` value outside.

Comment: I've added a real world example of the Flicker in use.

Comment: The sample code I proposed initially is not about the button having a state of its own. A variable called mode has the value of the string "On" or the string "Off", which changes by pressing the button. So it is with the intention of it being as simple as possible. The button's only function, rather than turning on or off a state, is about rendering on or off a whole `div` element with more jsx elements inside.

Comment: This is the fundamental intention of the Flicker class. And it's just to resolve a doubt, that is why the sample of the idea is a simple on or off switch. Don't get me wrong though, what you propose is just as valid, although not towards what my question was appointed.

Comment: @Dan - I think that my examples cover your case as well. However, you know your use case, and I don't :)

Comment: Oh, how so? Maybe there's more to it than what I understood?

Comment: You need two an On/Off button with the content near it, which appears when the state is `on`. If I understand your use case correctly, my 2nd example works for you. Look at it again (I've updated the names).